# Print a list of structs in scala without brackets "[" in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct

I have a column in a `Dataset[Row]` which is a list of structs in (Scala Spark) with the fields `id` (String) and `score` (Double). I need to convert the list of structs to a raw string in order to print it out without the `[` bracket symbols which are automatically appended to the end of each struct and the list when printing. For example, when I print the column out now it looks like this:

```
[[id1, 0.4], [id2, 0.2], [id3, 0.2], [id4, 0.2]]
```

but I need to remove the `[` on either end of the list and replace the `,` delimiters with `:` (or any delimiter which is not a `,`) like this (and maintain order):

```
id1, 0.4: id2, 0.2: id3, 0.2: id4, 0.2
```

I tried to use the `concat_ws` method however it only accepts `(array<string> or string)`. Is it possible to convert my list of structs to one long string?

Comment: whar do you mean by "printing" ? Why are you even "printing" your dataframens ?

Comment: I mean printing to a file of raw text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, DoubleType, StringType, StructType}

case class ScoreObj(id: String, score: Double)

case class Record(value: String, scores: List[ScoreObj])


object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    // create dataframe with test data
    val data = Seq(
      Row("aaa", List(Row("id1", 0.4), Row("id2", 0.5)))
    )

    val schema = new StructType()
      .add("value", StringType)
      .add("scores", ArrayType(new StructType()
        .add("id", StringType)
        .add("score", DoubleType)))

    val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)

    df.show(false)
//    +-----+------------------------+
//    |value|scores                  |
//    +-----+------------------------+
//    |aaa  |[[id1, 0.4], [id2, 0.5]]|
//    +-----+------------------------+

    // transform the array column into string
    df.as[Record].map { case Record(value: String, scores: Seq[ScoreObj]) =>
      (value, scores.map { case ScoreObj(id, score) => s"$id, $score" }.mkString(": "))
    }.toDF("value", "scores_str").show()

//    +-----+------------------+
//    |value|        scores_str|
//    +-----+------------------+
//    |  aaa|id1, 0.4: id2, 0.5|
//    +-----+------------------+
  }
}
```

Comment: why are implicits being used? can you use this without implicits?

Comment: `spark.implicits._` is used here in order to convert scala objects into Dataset (`df.as[Record]`). Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one solution. Starting dataset:

```scala
df.show(false)
// +------------------------------------------------+
// |foo                                             |
// +------------------------------------------------+
// |[{id1, 0.4}, {id2, 0.2}, {id3, 0.2}, {id4, 0.2}]|
// +------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- foo: array (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
//  |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = false)
```

To arrive at the desired string representation, transform each element of the array into a string using `transform` with `concat_ws`, then combine array elements into a string using `array_join`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(
  array_join(
    transform(col("foo"), c => concat_ws(", ", c.getField("id"), c.getField("score"))),
    ": "
  ) as "foo_str"
).show(false)
// +--------------------------------------+
// |foo_str                               |
// +--------------------------------------+
// |id1, 0.4: id2, 0.2: id3, 0.2: id4, 0.2|
// +--------------------------------------+
```

`transform(c, f: (Column) => Column)` runs over the elements of the array column `c` and applies `f` to each element. In that case, `f` calls `concat_ws` and since the input to `f` is a column of structs, we use `getField("x")` to select the value of field `x`. This results in an array of strings that can be concatenated into a single string using `array_join`.

Comment: when I try to run this code I get a too many arguments exception:   error: too many arguments for method transform: (rule: PartialFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression,org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression])org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression

Comment: @219CID What is your version of Spark? `transform()` is from Spark 3.0.0. Documentation is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column). Search for "transform" in the search field because it seems the link does not open the correct section as it should.